# PC doesn't turn on after updating

Tags: boot, updates

Yesterday I updated my laptop and turned it off after the update finished.
Today, when I tried to turn it on, nothing happened, and I do mean *nothing*.
No LED indicators, sounds, screen or basically any sign of activity upon pressing the power button.

I tried checking the battery, by plugging the charger. The battery LED didnt even turn on, so I decided to take it to repair. The technician spent a couple hours trying different things and simply couldn't point out a single hardware problem that could be causing it.

Bear in mind that this is the second time this problem occurred within a month. Last time, the pc came back to life after being left aside for a day. Problem is, I need it to work and can't afford to wait.

Any suggestions or ideas on it?

Comment: Try power resetting the laptop.  Pull the power cord and if you can pull the battery.  Then press the power button a few times.  Then add the power back and power on the laptop.  If you cannot remove the battery, remove the power cord still.  Then hold down the power button for 30 seconds.  Add the power cord back and power on.  If it will not power on you have bad hardware.

Comment: @Terrance suggestion is a good one. I had a similar issue twice with my previous laptop. It was a Toshiba and the way to do it was to remove the battery and pressing and holding the power button for 30 seconds, then connect the power cord and turn on.

Comment: Tried both approaches, no results though.

Comment: You're probably looking at a bad motherboard in the system.  To know for sure, try removing any added RAM or replace RAM that is there, remove the hard drive, etc.  It can be a lot of work to do, especially on a laptop since items are in the case and not easily removed.  If the technician that looked at your system tried another power supply then my honest thought is that the motherboard itself is bad.

Answer (score 0):

At poweron, a PC will run a Power On Self Test (POST). An OS can't stop or break that.

Your hardware is faulty. Since you cannot find the fault, replace the hardware.

The update seems like coincidence.

Comment: Sometimes a fault will prevent the POST from running, but you still might get a "beep" code specifying an error.  Count the beeps, then check the vendor documentation for the meaning.  I had a frozen disk which prevented POST, but still got the beep code.